# How does Ito's formula work at a point where the function/derivative is undefined? E.g. $x=(0,...,0)$ and $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert^{p}$

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

How does Ito's formula work at a point where the function is undefined? Consider $(0,...,0)=x\in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert^{p},\; p\geq 1$ where $\lvert x\rvert^{p}:=(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{\frac{p}{2}}$

Now for the Ito vector process $X_{t}:=(X_{t}^{1},...,X_{t}^{n})$ we obtain, where $X_{t}\neq 0$,

$d\lvert X_{t}\rvert^{p}=\lvert X_{t} \rvert^{p-2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_{t}^{j}+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k,l=1}^{n} (p-2)\lvert X_{t}\rvert ^{p-4}X_{t}^{k}X_{t}^{l}+1_{\{k=l\}}\lvert X_{t}\rvert^{p-2}$

I hope that is is correct, but anyhow do I just "ignore" the case when $X_{t}=(0,...,0)$ or is there a special way I can treat it?

Comment: One standard way to work with $|x|^p$ is to replace it by $(\varepsilon^2+|x|^2)^{p/2}$, which is smooth, apply our reasoning to this function, and at the end investigate what happens when $\varepsilon \to 0$. Hope it works for you.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}(|X_t| > 0 \text{ for all }t > 0) = 1$ (like a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^3$), this is correct.  Otherwise, you likely need to do something with local time or only defining the integrals up to a stopping time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both comments you got are correct, but I'll just expand a bit. Probably you need to handle these on a case-by-case basis. As Michal says, you can add an $\epsilon$ to make the function smooth, and then try to let $\epsilon$ go to zero and show that everything works properly. In many cases in higher dimensions (e.g. Brownian motion in three dimensions or more, as user6... says) the process will avoid the trouble set with probability 1 anyway, since it is transient, and so you would hopefully be ok.

There's a special case worth mentioning, that user6... alludes to. That is when you are working in one dimension, let's just say with Brownian motion, and $f(x) = |x|$. Then, formally, the first derivative is $sgn(x)$, which is 1 for positive $x$ and $-1$ for negative $x$ (its definition at $x=0$ doesn't matter here), and the second derivative is $\delta(x)$, the Dirac delta function. Ito's formula should therefore give

$$
|B_t|-|B_0| = \int_0^t sgn(B_s)dB_s + \int_0^t \delta(B_s)ds.
$$

Remarkably, although this is just a formal identity it turns out to be correct, with the last term equal to a new process, the local time of the Brownian motion. This is not a simple matter, and many researchers have worked on developing the properties of this and related processes. A good book if you're interested in this topic is "Markov Processes, Gaussian Processes, and Local Times", by Marcus and Rosen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1, Schilling , in his book, works the Ito formula on a similar function by using Friedrichs mollifiers on a slight modification of $|x|$, the modifications being at least $C^1$. Karatzas and Shreve have a generalized version of the Ito formula for convex functions, and hence sums of convex functions as well. This is done via a "second derivative measure" which turns out to work for the case you present as well. Of course, that involves the Brownian local time. The nice news is that semimartingales admitting local time also admit similar transformation formulas.